# Accessing elements from a Python list using Boolean indexing

Tags: python, list, slice

I recently came across this way of indexing a list in Python. I've never seen this one before, so I would like to understand this clearly.

I have a list `["Peter", "James", "Mark"]` and if I index it using the boolean value `False` it returns `Peter` and if I index it using `True` it returns `James`, as given below

- `["Peter", "James", "Mark"][False] => Peter`
- `["Peter", "James", "Mark"][True] => James`

I would like to know what happens here and what is this method called as?

Comment: @xg.plt.py, I was wrong. Have a look at wim's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The datamodel hook here is the [`__index__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/) magic method:

```
>>> True.__index__()
1
>>> False.__index__()
0
```

The value returned by on obj's `__index__` is used when accessing with [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), allowing arbitrary objects to be used for indexing and slicing:

```
x[obj]
```

This is somewhat independent of the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`!  You may achieve the same with any object.

```
>>> class A:
...     def __index__(self):
...         return 1
...     
>>> 'ab'[A()]
'b'
```

Whether `__index__` is resolved for `int` subclasses depends on implementation detail.

CPython 3.7.1:

```
>>> class MyInt(int):
...     def __index__(self):
...         return 1
... 
>>> '01'[MyInt(0)]
'0'
```

PyPy 5.0.1:

```
>>>> class MyInt(int):
....     def __index__(self):
....         return 1
....         
>>>> '01'[MyInt(0)]
'1'
```

PyPy behaves correctly according to the [Python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).  Looks like CPython is taking a shortcut / performance optimization.

Comment: A `MyInt` is already an int, so Python doesn't actually need to perform a conversion to int. I'd say both results are consistent with the data model.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `bool` class is derived from of `int`
Hence `True=1` and `False=0`

`print (True + True)` will give an output `2`

So on a list `['peter', 'john', 'abhi'][True]` returns 2nd element of the list i.e. `john`