# Understanding multiplication syntax with Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I understand the below `list concatenation:`

```
r = [1, 2] + [False]
# Output: r = [1, 2, False]
```

However, I am not able to understand the below syntax:

```
r = [1, 2][False]
# Output: 1
```

Comment: Maybe dupe: [Accessing elements from a Python list using Boolean indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49633222/674039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining an unnamed `list`, then indexing it with `False`. Because `False` has a numeric value of zero (`bool` is actually a subclass of `int`, where `False` has a value `0`, and `True` has a value `1`), that's equivalent to indexing it as index `0`, so it's like you wrote:

```
__unnamed = [1, 2]
r = __unnamed[0]
```